# Compare 2 columns to create another

Tags: google-sheets

I need to compare the item in Column A with all the items in Column B, if this item is not present in Column B, it is generated in Column C. What formula do I need to use to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:A; NOT(COUNTIF(B2:B; A2:A)))
```

[image]